# Create a Nutch 2.x plugin using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, web-crawler, hbase, nutch

I have to write a plugin to parse crawled content vy Nutch 2.3.1. I have decided to use eclipse as Its better than simple editor. Now How can I create a plugin in eclipse and test it via some simple use case ?

Comment: Eclipse plug-ins are complex things, this question is far too broad.

Comment: I just need a hint as I have not worked on eclipse

Answer (score 2):

You can use following steps to get the plugin working from Eclipse.

1. Get Nutch source code.

   `git clone https://github.com/apache/nutch.git`
2. Switch to 2.3.1 branch. If you want latest 2.x in development, you can use 2.x branch 
   https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/branch-2.3.1
3. Import project in eclipse.
4. Build for eclipse. It uses `ant` for build and has `eclipse` target.

   `ant eclipse`
5. All available plugins in nutch are under `src/plugins` directory.
6. You need a smilar structure for your new plugin so copy one of the existing plugin to new one.

   `cp -r lib-http my-http`

7 Now check the structure of plugin directory. It should be as below.

```
my-http/
├── build.xml
├── ivy.xml
├── plugin.xml
└── src
    ├── java
    └── test
```

8. `plugin.xml` is the one which has definitions for extentions, extention-points, runtime libraries etc. You can view it in eclipse plugin editor and can do changes from there.
9. Add proper implementation class and tests. Map that for extension  in `plugin.xml`
10. You have to change your `build.xml` and `ivy.xml` to add proper dependencies.
11. You can override targets defined in `src/plugin/build-plugin.xml` in your `build.xml`. `build-plugin.xml` is being called by main build file `src/build.xml` for each plugin.
12. You can test your plugin by using ant from the plugin directory.
    `ant test`.

You can also use eclipse to check JUint test results. Click on Test class and Run as `JUnit Test`

13. Add plugin to deploy and test targets in `src/plugin/build.xml`. This file is used by the main build file

    `<ant dir="my-http" target="deploy"/>`
14. add any required dependencies in `build/ivy/ivy.xml`
15. Add plugin `plugin.includes` property in `conf/nutch-site.xml`
16. Build nutch

    `ant runtime`

Now your plugin is set to run in local/distributed mode from `runtime` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any editor you want to write your code, as long as you generate a `jar` that you load in the Nutch plugin system with the right dependencies and configurations in the xml file everything should work. You can check https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/RunNutchInEclipse that contains detailed instructions to open and  **run** within eclipse so debugging is easier, but its not required. Specially important is to run `ant eclipse` in your local copy of the project, so that you can open the Nutch entire source code in Eclipse, once this is done you can create your plugin file structure and start coding.

Hope it helps.